# Can't log in to Samba PDC with domain account

Tags: 11.04, networking, samba, pam

I have a problem. I like to login on a Samba Server with my Ubuntu 10.04/11.04 PC. On my Samba Server there are some accounts with data, but I couldn't connect to it. I have done this:

```
aptitude -y install winbind smbclient
mv /etc/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba/smb.conf.original
vim /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Contents of the file:

```
[global]
workgroup = LAN
idmap uid = 10000-20000
idmap gid = 10000-20000
template shell = /bin/bash
template homedir = /home/%D/%U
winbind enum users = yes
winbind enum groups = yes
winbind cache time = 10
winbind separator = +
winbind use default domain = yes
security = domain
password server = *
encrypt passwords = yes
domain master = no
local master = no
preferred master = no
os level = 0
```

Then I have done this:

```
/etc/init.d/winbind restart
net rpc join -S 192.168.0.253 -U Administrator 
wbinfo -u //no result
vim /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

I wrote into the file `nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:         compat winbind
group:          compat winbind
shadow:         compat
```

After that I did this:

```
/etc/init.d/winbind restart
vim /etc/security/group.conf
```

I edited the file `group.conf`:

```
* ; * ; * ; Al0000-2400 ; floppy, audio, cdrom, video, usb, plugdev, users

vim /etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth required   pam_group.so use_first_pass 
auth sufficient pam_winbind.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok_secure use_first_pass
auth required   pam_deny.so

vim /etc/pam.d/sudo
auth sufficient pam_winbind.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so use_first_pass
auth required   pam_deny.so
@include common-account
```

And after I have done all this, I get the error message: "No logon Server", when I try to login with my account from the Samba Server. But if I try to login with my local account I get the same message but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have not configured your server as a PDC - for a DC you need to set "domain master = yes". The setup of winbind and use of various other parameters is also not necessary on a DC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set security to user. If using as a primary domain controller, set domain logons, domain master, local master, and preferred master to yes.

Also, set os level to anything higher than 32.